# Photoshop script to get image layer transform information（not bounds）

Tags: javascript, photoshop

[the bounds of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9N0d.png)

I can get the bounds by the activeLayer.layer.bounds[0]. but it's not include transparent area

and the information what i need is:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s2QV.png)

how can i get it.

Comment: activeLayer.layer.bounds[0]..[3] gives you the top, left, bottom and right of the active layer. Can you not take that away from the image width and height to give you the coordinates from the top left hand corner?

Comment: The bounds are the bounding box's size, not the imported image. I'm trying to use ActionManager.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old script (from 2010) by pattesdours, hopefully it will give you want you are after:

```
// This script exports extended layer.bounds information
// by pattesdours

// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF

var srcDoc = activeDocument;

var docWidth = srcDoc.width.value;
var docHeight = srcDoc.height.value;
var theLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer;
var layerData = cLayer(srcDoc, theLayer);

var str = theLayer.name + "\n"
  + "pos " + leftTop + "\n"
  + "width " + layerData.layerWidth + "\n"
  + "height " + layerData.layerHeight + "\n" + "\n"

alert(str);

displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // ON

// class using a contructor
function cLayer(doc, layer)
{

  this.layerWidth = layer.bounds[2].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.layerHeight = layer.bounds[3].value - layer.bounds[1].value;

  // these return object coordinates relative to canvas
  this.upperLeftX = layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.upperLeftY = layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.upperCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2 + layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.upperCenterY = layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.upperRightX = layer.bounds[2].value;
  this.upperRightY = layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.middleLeftX = layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.middleLeftY = this.layerHeight / 2 + layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.middleCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2 + layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.middleCenterY = this.layerHeight / 2 + layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.middleRightX = layer.bounds[2].value;
  this.middleRightY = this.layerHeight / 2 + layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.lowerLeftX = layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.lowerLeftY = layer.bounds[3].value;
  this.lowerCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2 + layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.lowerCenterY = layer.bounds[3].value;
  this.lowerRightX = layer.bounds[2].value;
  this.lowerRightY = layer.bounds[3].value;

  // I'm adding these for easier editing of flash symbol transformation point (outputs a 'x, y' format)
  // because I like to assign shortcut keys that use the numeric pad keyboard, like such:
  //    7 8 9
  //    4 5 6
  //    1 2 3
  //
  this.leftBottom = this.lowerLeftX + ", " + this.lowerLeftY;
  this.bottomCenter = this.lowerCenterX + ", " + this.lowerCenterY;
  this.rightBottom = this.lowerRightX + ", " + this.lowerRightY;

  this.leftCenter = this.middleLeftX + ", " + this.middleLeftY;
  this.center = this.middleCenterX + ", " + this.middleCenterY;
  this.rightCenter = this.middleRightX + ", " + this.middleRightY;

  this.leftTop = this.upperLeftX + ", " + this.upperLeftY;
  this.topCenter = this.upperCenterX + ", " + this.upperCenterY;
  this.rightTop = this.upperRightX + ", " + this.upperRightY;

  // these return object coordinates relative to layer bounds
  this.relUpperLeftX = layer.bounds[1].value - layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.relUpperLeftY =  layer.bounds[0].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.relUpperCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2;
  this.relUpperCenterY = layer.bounds[0].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.relUpperRightX = this.layerWidth;
  this.relUpperRightY = layer.bounds[0].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
  this.relMiddleLeftX = layer.bounds[1].value - layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.relMiddleLeftY = this.layerHeight / 2;
  this.relMiddleCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2;
  this.relMiddleCenterY = this.layerHeight / 2;
  this.relMiddleRightX = this.layerWidth;
  this.relMiddleRightY = this.layerHeight / 2;
  this.relLowerLeftX = layer.bounds[1].value - layer.bounds[1].value;
  this.relLowerLeftY = this.layerHeight;
  this.relLowerCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2;
  this.relLowerCenterY = this.layerHeight / 2;
  this.relLowerRightY = this.layerHeight;
  this.relLowerRightX = this.layerWidth;
  this.relLowerRightY = this.layerHeight;

  return this;
}
```